# Mousenter, leave function event jquery

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mouseleave

What's wrong with this code. It doesn't work.

```
$(".sider").on("mouseenter") function(event){
$(".sider-post").fadeIn(350);
}).on("mouseleave") function(event){
$(".sider-post").fadeOut(350);
});
```

Here's the html, the sider should be visible-the border, but the child should fade.
thanks

```
<div class="sider" style="border:2px dotted black">
<div class="sider-post" style="background:black;">some content</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: HTML should also be here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving `)` at the place of `,` after `events`.

Should be this

```
$(".siderr").on("mouseenter", function(event){
  $(".sider-post").fadeIn(350);
}).on("mouseleave", function(event){
   $(".sider-post").fadeOut(350);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/30/)

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
$(".siderr").mouseenter( function(event){
$(".sider-post").fadeIn(350);
});

$(".siderr").mouseleave( function(event){
$(".sider-post").fadeOut(350);
});
```

hope this may useful